# Word doc: Pagination changes

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have an MS word document that just barely fits on one page.  Sometimes when I open the document, it fits on one page.  Other times I open the same document without any modification in between, there's a line spilling over to the second page.  What controls this?

Comment: Do you open it on the same computer? If not then different printer drivers can be a problem or even a different OS according to this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother/why-does-my-document-layout-change-on-different/f3d67784-500d-49a7-9fd7-db5936189b16

Comment: Yep, same computer.

Comment: I've experienced this before, though not so much in more recent versions of Word. The conclusion I reached is that sometimes Word just interprets the various font metrics and/or computes values such as line spacing a tiny bit differently (esp. if they're not specified as exact values). Most of the time, the differences aren't noticeable though. My recollection is that older versions of Segoe used to cause me particular problems. What font are you using, and have you tried others?

Comment: Is there an automatic field in the document, like a date or time, that may change in width (like the difference in width between `1/9/2016` and `31/10/2016`)?

Comment: @Atzmon Good question, but the answer is no. There are no fields in the documents I most often notice this with.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this is almsot always the result of changing the printer (for example from home printer to networked printer at work, or changing to "print to pdf")  Different printer can change margins in small ways, which, in turn, can change pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem, found that MS Word was unexpectedly adding a header to the doc after I use the "check for issues" to inspect the document.  To resolve it, I would double click the header (which is empty), then double click back into the main document - thus, the "blank" header would go away, giving some space back at the top of the document again.  I can't seem to prevent MS Word from adding the header back again if I re-inspect the doc, though.
[using MS Office Professional Plux 2016 ver 1702 (build 7870.2031)